# Selecting the All Coordinate values using xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I am using xarray to read the data from netcdf files.

I am exporting the data for any given data variable to CSV format.

Here is a sample data variable

```
stratiform_snowfall_rate    (time, grid_latitude, grid_longitude) float32
Dimensions  = ('time', 'grid_latitude', 'grid_longitude')
No.of Dimensions  = 3
DataType    = float32
Shape       = (36, 548, 421)
```

I can get the individual values from the DataArray.

However, I want a unique set of values for each Coordinate.

i.e I want all the latitude longitude and time values for which I have the snowfall_rate data.

There should be 36 Unique time values, 548 latitude values, and 421 longitude values.

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: does [`ds.to_dataframe().to_csv(filepath)`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_dataframe.html) work?

Comment: Hi Machael, not sure how the to_csv() will store if there are multiple variables. I want each variable to get stored in a separate csv file and also when i tried to save it as csv i am getting Memory Error:numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 19.8 PiB for an array with shape (36, 548, 421, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 421, 547, 3) and data type float32.

Comment: Can you fully describe the issue you're trying to solve in the question? Note that you can loop over the variables in `ds.data_vars` and do `ds[v].to_series().to_frame(name=v).to_csv()`. That said, yes, csv is not a good format for storing high-dimensional data and you'd be much better off leaving the data as a netcdf.

Comment: note that to_dataframe() *will* store multiple variables in a dataset, but all arrays in the dataset will first be broadcast against one another and then stacked. So this doesn't work well with arrays with non-uniform dimensions. This can lead to size explosions you're seeing with the array allocation error.

Comment: Michael, i am trying to get the unique set of coordinates for a given Data Variable. As i am trying to store the data for a given Data Variable along with the coordinates in it's own csv/parquet file and eventually in a db table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I am able to read the coordinate values.

Here is a sample ex:

```
dataArray = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randn(4, 6),
    dims=("x", "y"),
    coords={
        "x": [-3.2, 2.1, 5.3, 6.5],
        "y": pd.date_range("2009-01-05", periods=6, freq="M"),
    },
)

for i in range(len(dataArray.x)):
    for j in range(len(dataArray.y)):
        rowDict = {}
        rowDict['x'] = dataArray.coords['x'].values[i]
        rowDict['y'] = pd.to_datetime(str(dataArray.coords['y'].values[j])).strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%S')
        rowDict['val'] = dataArray.data[i, j]
        print(rowDict)
```

And I am getting the output as :

```
{'x': -3.2, 'y': '2009.01.31 00.00.00', 'val': 1.1672918170123077}
{'x': -3.2, 'y': '2009.02.28 00.00.00', 'val': -0.45000573967001745}
{'x': -3.2, 'y': '2009.03.31 00.00.00', 'val': -0.3070507637309568}
{'x': -3.2, 'y': '2009.04.30 00.00.00', 'val': -0.16715901864646582}
{'x': -3.2, 'y': '2009.05.31 00.00.00', 'val': 1.6700002681882784}
{'x': -3.2, 'y': '2009.06.30 00.00.00', 'val': 0.2303405222447574}
{'x': 2.1, 'y': '2009.01.31 00.00.00', 'val': -0.10394183859025365}
{'x': 2.1, 'y': '2009.02.28 00.00.00', 'val': -0.6399654408544677}
{'x': 2.1, 'y': '2009.03.31 00.00.00', 'val': -0.7322155474326156}
{'x': 2.1, 'y': '2009.04.30 00.00.00', 'val': 0.4443732649765692}
{'x': 2.1, 'y': '2009.05.31 00.00.00', 'val': 0.32141177764826817}
{'x': 2.1, 'y': '2009.06.30 00.00.00', 'val': 0.990286185910961}
{'x': 5.3, 'y': '2009.01.31 00.00.00', 'val': -1.0176437927897097}
{'x': 5.3, 'y': '2009.02.28 00.00.00', 'val': -0.23011079013897445}
{'x': 5.3, 'y': '2009.03.31 00.00.00', 'val': -0.17623947662095518}
{'x': 5.3, 'y': '2009.04.30 00.00.00', 'val': -1.567830106123095}
{'x': 5.3, 'y': '2009.05.31 00.00.00', 'val': 0.3510704631729717}
{'x': 5.3, 'y': '2009.06.30 00.00.00', 'val': -1.619554124545969}
{'x': 6.5, 'y': '2009.01.31 00.00.00', 'val': -0.7614693432763142}
{'x': 6.5, 'y': '2009.02.28 00.00.00', 'val': 1.1021880682514598}
{'x': 6.5, 'y': '2009.03.31 00.00.00', 'val': -0.9944031641204935}
{'x': 6.5, 'y': '2009.04.30 00.00.00', 'val': 0.4910807257668136}
{'x': 6.5, 'y': '2009.05.31 00.00.00', 'val': 1.5922216407449592}
{'x': 6.5, 'y': '2009.06.30 00.00.00', 'val': -0.41559207408354637}
```